# How can I prevent color variants when painting over wall putty?

Tags: painting, paint, primer, putty

I have used putty on the wall to fix the holes, and fill some gaps. the putty color is white while the rest of the wall is an older light green, I am painting a very dark yellow, However when painting the putty will give a darker color than the rest of the wall. how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a primer/sealer on the entire wall, before painting.

[image]

Or select a paint and primer combination.

[image]

Or simply apply multiple coats of paint over the entire wall.

Comment: I've used the pictured paint and don't rate it as highly as separate primer/paint for stain/sheen blocking.  I've used several other combo paint/primers and would give the class a 20-30% improvement over straight paint.

Comment: @Tester101 - When you say apply multiple coats of paint, do you mean over the whole wall including the putty covered areas. or only the non putty covered areas?. thank

Comment: @Wahtever Spot "priming" with wall color paint, perhaps several spot "primes" until sheens are similar, then cover entire wall.